# Present view controller in a container view at collection view didSelectItemAtIndexPath swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicontainerview

I am trying to present a view controller in a container view when i select a cell from a collection view. The problem is that I can't seem to understand how to present it in the container below the collection view.
[image]

I tried:

```
if (indexPath.row == 0){

                // Presenting first view controller

    let detailedViewController: ViewController =
          self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController") as! ViewController

                self.presentViewController(detailedViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

How can I make it go to the container instead of presenting the whole view controller.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
self.addChildViewController(detailedViewController)
containerView.addSubview(detailedViewController.view)
```

Comment: Thanks, but how exactly do you do that because it gives me an error: 
Value of type ContainerViewController has no member addSubview

Comment: You must add subview to a view, not to a view controller.

Comment: I don't understand how to get the view of the ContainerViewController

Comment: How did you create an outlet to the container? Did you connect it in the storyboard? Show the code plz

Comment: Thank you for the help. I did it. I just forgot to use the proper variable.

Answer (score 1):

Swift 5.0 Use this functions to add and remove child VC:

```
private func add(asChildViewController viewController: UIViewController, childFrame:CGRect) {
        // Add Child View Controller
        addChild(viewController)

        // Add Child View as Subview
        view.addSubview(viewController.view)

        // Configure Child View
        viewController.view.frame = childFrame
        viewController.view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

        // Notify Child View Controller
        viewController.didMove(toParent: self)

    }
    private func remove(asChildViewController viewController: UIViewController) {
        // Notify Child View Controller
        viewController.willMove(toParent: nil)

        // Remove Child View From Superview
        viewController.view.removeFromSuperview()

        // Notify Child View Controller
        viewController.removeFromParent()
    }
```

adopted from [here](https://cocoacasts.com/managing-view-controllers-with-container-view-controllers/)